# Linq to SQL assistance with joins

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, join

Please can you help me translate the following SQL query into LINQ
Its mainly the joins that i am having issues with.
The result will be LINQ to SQL code which gets executed.

many thanks

```
SELECT * FROM   unit INNER JOIN   

 unit_measurement_total ON unit.prime_measurement_uri = unit_measurement_total.uri RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   property_expense_schedule 
        INNER JOIN
     unit_apportionment ON property_expense_schedule.uri = unit_apportionment.property_expense_schedule_uri 
        INNER JOIN
      unit_apportionment_date ON unit_apportionment.uri = unit_apportionment_date.unit_apportionment_uri ON 
     unit_measurement_total.property_ref = unit_apportionment.property_ref
        WHERE (property_expense_schedule.property_ref = ...)
```

This is the LINQ I have at the moment, but its not generating the same results as the SQL query. So i am going wrong with the joins and the right outer joins.

```
 var query = (from units in context.units
                 join unitmestot in context.unit_measurement_total on units.prime_measurement_uri equals unitmestot.uri
                 from pes in context.property_expense_schedule
                 join unitapp in context.unit_apportionment on new { A = pes.uri, B = unitmestot.property_ref, C = unitmestot.unit_ref } equals new { A = unitapp.property_expense_schedule_uri, B = unitapp.property_ref, C = unitapp.unit_ref}
                 join unitappdate in context.unit_apportionment_date on unitapp.uri equals unitappdate.unit_apportionment_uri
                 select new Apportionment()
                 {
                     PropertyRef = units.property_ref.ToString(),
                     ScheduleName = pes.name,
                     ScheduleRef = pes.@ref.ToString(),
                     PropertyExpenseScheduleUri = pes.uri,
                     UnitRef = units.@ref.ToString(),
                     UnitName = "(" + units.@ref.ToString() + ")" + units.name,
                     ObseleteUnit = units.obsolete_unit,
                     ApportionmentPercentage = unitappdate.apportionment_percentage,
                     ToDate = unitappdate.to_date,
                     MeasurementBasis = unitmestot.measurement_basis,
                     MeasuredIn = unitmestot.measured_in,
                     MeasurementImperialTotal = unitmestot.measurement_imperial_total,
                     MeasurementMetricTotal = unitmestot.measurement_metric_total

                 }).Where(filter);
```

the latest code you supplied generates the following SQL and returns 0 rows.

```
  SELECT     [Extent1].[uri] AS [uri],     CASE WHEN ([Join3].[property_ref1] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE  CAST( [Join3].[property_ref1] AS nvarchar(max)) END AS [C1],     [Extent3].[name] AS [name],      CAST( [Extent3].[ref] AS nvarchar(max)) AS [C2],     [Extent3].[uri] AS [uri1],     CASE WHEN ([Join3].[ref] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE  CAST( [Join3].[ref] AS nvarchar(max)) END AS [C3],     N'(' + CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN ([Join3].[ref] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE  CAST( [Join3].[ref] AS nvarchar(max)) END IS NULL) THEN N'' WHEN ([Join3].[ref] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE  CAST( [Join3].[ref] AS nvarchar(max)) END + N')' + CASE WHEN ([Join3].[name] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE [Join3].[name] END AS [C4],     [Join3].[obsolete_unit] AS [obsolete_unit],     [Extent2].[apportionment_percentage] AS [apportionment_percentage],     [Extent2].[to_date] AS [to_date],     CASE WHEN ([Join3].[measurement_basis] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE [Join3].[measurement_basis] END AS [C5],     CASE WHEN ([Join3].[measured_in] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE [Join3].[measured_in] END AS [C6],     [Join3].[measurement_imperial_total] AS [measurement_imperial_total],     [Join3].[measurement_metric_total] AS [measurement_metric_total]    FROM    [tramps].[unit_apportionment] AS [Extent1]    INNER JOIN [tramps].[unit_apportionment_date] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[uri] = [Extent2].[unit_apportionment_uri]    INNER JOIN [tramps].[property_expense_schedule] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[property_expense_schedule_uri] = [Extent3].[uri]    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent4].[property_ref] AS [property_ref2], [Extent4].[measurement_basis] AS [measurement_basis], [Extent4].[measured_in] AS [measured_in], [Extent4].[measurement_imperial_total] AS [measurement_imperial_total], [Extent4].[measurement_metric_total] AS [measurement_metric_total], [Extent5].[property_ref] AS [property_ref1], [Extent5].[ref] AS [ref], [Extent5].[name] AS [name], [Extent5].[obsolete_unit] AS [obsolete_unit]        FROM  [tramps].[unit_measurement_total] AS [Extent4]        INNER JOIN [tramps].[unit] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent4].[uri] = [Extent5].[prime_measurement_uri] ) AS [Join3] ON [Extent1].[property_ref] = [Join3].[property_ref2]    WHERE (N'101329' = (CASE WHEN ([Join3].[property_ref1] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE  CAST( [Join3].[property_ref1] AS nvarchar(max)) END)) AND ( NOT (('Y' = [Join3].[obsolete_unit]) AND ([Join3].[obsolete_unit] IS NOT NULL)))
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you have tried and what specific issue you are experiencing?  Right now you are asking people to write your code for you.

Comment: i have updated the question

Comment: I think you can use https://www.linqpad.net/ for the learning curve, it's just a matter of learning nothing too complex.

Comment: You should use `DefaultIfEmpty` to express `right outer join`.

Comment: thanks i have used linq pad to understand it all, which is how i produced the LINQ.

If the generated SQL is re-manipulated to the originial SQL it should return the same results??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ does not support **Right Outer Join**, so it should be simulated by swapping the left and right parts and performing a **Left Outer Join** (which is not so natural, but at least the pattern in known - [join clause (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx)).

With that being said, I think the equivalent LINQ query should be something like this:

```
from unitapp in context.unit_apportionment
    join unitappdate in context.unit_apportionment_date on unitapp.uri equals unitappdate.unit_apportionment_uri
    join pes in context.property_expense_schedule on unitapp.property_expense_schedule_uri equals pes.uri
    join unitmestot in context.unit_measurement_total on unitapp.property_ref equals unitmestot.property_ref
        into unitapp_unitmesstot from unitmestot in unitapp_unitmesstot.DefaultIfEmpty() // Left Outer Join
    join units in context.units on unitmestot.uri equals units.prime_measurement_uri
       select new Apportionment()
       {
           // ...
       }
```

**EDIT:** Looks like EF is generating additional criteria for the inner join right after the left outer join which is causing differences with the original SQL query. In such case you can try grouping the right part into a subquery in attempt to change the join order:

```
    from unitapp in context.unit_apportionment
    join unitappdate in context.unit_apportionment_date on unitapp.uri equals unitappdate.unit_apportionment_uri
    join pes in context.property_expense_schedule on unitapp.property_expense_schedule_uri equals pes.uri
    join right in (
        from unitmestot in context.unit_measurement_total
        join units in context.units on unitmestot.uri equals units.prime_measurement_uri
        select new { unitmestot, units } 
    ) on unitapp.property_ref equals right.unitmestot.property_ref
    into outerJoin from right in outerJoin.DefaultIfEmpty() // Left Outer Join
    let unitmestot = right.unitmestot
    let units = right.units
    select new Apportionment()
    {
       // ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but its still not right. 
Do you think the order of the LINQ tables matter, when compared to the order of the SQL tables?

Comment: For inner joins it really doesn't matter. For outer joins it matters of course. What is the difference - returning less records? Btw, is the LINQ to Entities? Can you add `var sql = query.ToString();` and post the result.

Comment: I had to reject your edit due to the site rules - you should posted it as update in your question. Anyway, I see additional condition in the last inner join of the generated sql that might cause the difference. I'll update the answer with alternative, but unfortunately can't test it because it really depends on your entity model that I don't have.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry didnt know about the rules, good to know for next time. yeah the updated code would be appreciated. sure i understand, i can test it.
thank you.

Comment: unfortunately it returned 0 rows, i have posted the generated SQL as an edit.
Surely the SQL query must be possible in LINQ ?

Comment: Now the joins are ok. Most likely there is a difference in `where` conditions. For instance, from what I see, SQL query has `property_expense_schedule.property_ref = ...` while the LINQ query seems to be using `unit.schedule.property_ref = ...` which basically kills the outer join.